# Error when restore sql database from .bak file

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, restore

When I restore SQL database by using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, it fails and give  me this message:

[image: restore error]

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Restore failed for Server 'app1'. 
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=9.00.1399.00&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Restore+Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing
>   a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ---
>
> The file or filegroup
>   "SilosFollow_log" cannot be selected
>   for this operation. RESTORE DATABASE
>   is terminating abnormally. (Microsoft
>   SQL Server, Error: 3219)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=09.00.1399&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=3219&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> OK

NB Database owner is not the backup user name.

Comment: You should consider asking this on ServerFault.com.

Answer (score 1):

When you configure the restore, make sure you aren't using data/log files that are in use by a database that is currently running (probably the database you're restoring on top of).

It makes the data directory a mess, but I give my data/log files a Rev. number when I restore databases so I don't run into that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure SilosFollow_log is a database backup and not a transaction log backup?

In order to restore transaction log backups you must first have restored a full database backup and any differential backups. Then you can restore the transaction log backups in turn.